# How can I detect all the sub folders under a giving main folder?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, system.io.directory

Assume my path is `"c:/myapp/mainfolder/"`
there are three folder included in the main folder. 
BTW, It doesn't need to identify separate files under mainfolder.

```
c:/myapp/mainfolder/subfolder1/
c:/myapp/mainfolder/subfolder2/
c:/myapp/mainfolder/subfolder3/
```

How can I input `c:/myapp/mainfoder/`
and get the output: `string[] subArrFolders = {subfolder1, subfolder2, subfolder3}`

C#2.0 using.

Thank you.

Comment: Clarification: Did you want just the sub-folder name, or the full directory path?

Comment: Sure, I want just the sub-folder name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Directory.GetDireatories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) to get the sub directories of a known path. You can use it like this:

```
string MyPath = "c:\\myapp\\mainfolder\\";
string[] subArrFolders = IO.Directory.GetDiretories(MyPath);
```

Comment: But he asked for the subfolder name, not the full path name. this answer gives you:
C:\myapp\mainfolder\subfolder1
C:\myapp\mainfolder\subfolder2
C:\myapp\mainfolder\subfolder3

Comment: Quite, right, although the original poster marked it as accepted, so I guess it was good enough.  If you want more meta data about the subdirectories, and not just their paths, you can use the DirectoryInfo (See MSDN) class.

Comment: Yes, I combined Kibbee's input and `DirectoryInfo` in my project.

Answer (score 1):

For lack of better information this answer assumes he asked for the sub-folder name, not the full path name, which is what that will give you:

This will allow you extract the leaf folder name:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace StackOverflow_NET
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String path = @"C:\myapp\mainfolder";
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            DirectoryInfo [] sub_directories = info.GetDirectories("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in sub_directories)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
subfolder1
subfolder2
subfolder3
```

The key difference here is the DirectoryInfo class allows you to get the leaf directory name via the Name property.

Comment: @C Johnson, Thanks a lot for your input.